# Best way to get timezone of user based on area code

Tags: php, timezone

I'm attempting to get a timezone of a user based on area code information that they provided.  I discovered the following resource on maxmind:

http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/api/php/timezone/

I suspect that I could use this with another api that provides the state that an area code belongs to.  I'm looking for a simple REST API that provides this info - or a robust scraping routine that achieve the same results.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of area code are you talking about? Postal zip codes? In all the countries?

Comment: Link above is dead

Comment: It's silly how difficult this data is to find.

Answer (score 5):

I'd caution against this approach. A lot of my friends (those in the 18 to 30 demographic) move across the country and keep their old cell phone numbers. The area code is less and less an indication of current location and more and more an indication of where someone lived at one time. With google voice accounts people might get an area code because they like the number and have never lived there!

Comment: Will - very true.  The product we are building is for physical offices (doctor's offices, etc) and so their office phone is what we're using to we're hoping to extrapolate their timezone (without explicitly asking them).

Comment: Then I'd recommend getting a list of area codes and building your own cross-reference in a table in your database. Here you go:
http://www.bennetyee.org/ucsd-pages/area.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any specific API made for this, but if you want to store the area code database locally, [NANPA](http://www.nanpa.com) is in charge of managing them.

Here's a good starting point http://www.nationalnanpa.com/area_codes/index.html

Comment: Scott - that seems to be a perfect starting point which I'll investigate further.  In the meantime, I used Verizon's website (which has an area code form and posted to this with curl and parsed the result page for the info I needed).  Super hacky and super unreliable but works (for now)...

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK with adding Javascript to your project, then you may want to try [ChronoMouse.js](http://www.chronomouse.com), which will help get the current time, GMT offset, time zone name, location, capital city, daylight savings laws, or daylight savings status for any US/Canada area code, or country code.

For country codes, the info is based off of the capital city.

For example:

```
console.log( getLocalInfo('+49').time.display );

// 15:07
```

For more examples and documentation, see [www.chronomouse.com](http://www.chronomouse.com).

Note: I am the author of the project.

Comment: Looks useful, but I have to ask... does it have anything to do with mouse clicks or mouse cursors? Most scripts and plugins with the word 'mouse' in their title, literally deal with mousing things, while your script doesn't seem to have any connection. Maybe you should seriously consider renaming your script. What about Chronowolf? You can still have your clock logo, just with different ears.